# springsource tool suite (eclipse) tutorial?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

any tutorial on this how to enable spring support for my existing project,and fast way to create my bean defination file.xml files..?

i know manually way of creating applicationcontex.xml..etc .but wonder is there any fast way when using springsource tool suite.   tutorial,article,video guide would be good

Answer (score 4):

If you have STS installed, when you right click on the project you should see a Spring entry on the context menu. You can then add the Spring nature to the project, which provides UI for things like the beans explorer in the project explorer view.

Once the project has the Spring nature, you should be easily able to create new beans definition files, which will use the editor geared towards editing those files.

If you don't have STS installed check http://blog.springsource.com/2009/08/06/springsource-tool-suite-210-now-available/ here for details of installing it by download or update site.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.